# Mark autosys job as SUCCESS even CMD fails

Tags: autosys

I have one autosys job.Job type is CMD.I am executing particular script and inside that script on particular condition I am exiting script with exit-code 99.Is there any way when script exits with exit-code 99 my autosys job should not fail but mark as SUCCESS?

Comment: Wrap the script in another script which exits with exit code 0 regardless?

Answer (score 2):

While defining job mentioned success_code.

e.g.

success_codes: 0,137

Answer (score 2):

You can actually do the coding in the script about that; like add some if-else in your script.

```
If [ $? -eq 99 ]
then
  exit 0
else
  exit $?
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

We can achieve your requirement by adding the following attribute in your CMD job JIL (job definition):

```
max_exit_success: 99
```